# How to get test summary in Minitest?

Tags: ruby, watir, minitest

I have automated my web tests with [Watir](http://watir.github.io) and [Minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest). I get this summary after I run the test.

> Finished in 417.061643s, 0.0168 runs/s, 0.0719 assertions/s.
>
> 1) Failure:
>   Map#test_maps_analysis_mode_ku060s [C:/Projects/Cbs Sandbox/tests/watir/map.rb:63]:
>   Total die used.
>   Expected: "103"
>
> Actual: "102"
>
> 2) Error:
>   Map#test_maps:
>   Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 10 seconds, waiting for false condition on #"overlay"}>
>
> 7 runs, 30 assertions, 1 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

I need to get the summary in an email. If possible, I also want to include the list of tests that were successful.

How to do that?

Comment: https://chriskottom.com/blog/2014/06/dress-up-your-minitest-output/

you can print test names, or store it in array. or even call mailer but right now out of the box, this functionality is not provided.

Comment: Or override default reporter, http://nandovieira.com/creating-custom-minitest-reporters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Rake to run all the tests as one ruby application.

First, `gem install rake`

Then file called 'Rakefile' to your root project folder with a code similar to this:

```
require "rake/testtask"

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
    t.test_files = FileList['tests/**/*_test.rb'] #my directory to tests is 'tests' you can change at you will
end
desc "Run tests"

task default: :test
```

Add a simple console minitest reporter somewhere in your project(preferably in test_helper.rb, which is the superclass for all your tests):

```
Minitest::Reporters.use! [Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new]
```

Lastly, I use next batch script to store log in a file:

```
Type NUL > results.log
call rake >> results.log
```

In the end of a results.log file a summary of a test run is provided:

```
Finished in 631.09969s
47 tests, 105 assertions, 10 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

You can then parse the results.

Comment: Can I read the test summary using rake ? I need to send an email after reading the summary.

Comment: I'd rather use some other tool for that - rake is for build automation. But you can try - I don't have much experience with rake itself; apparently sending mails is not hard from rake - https://gist.github.com/eignerchris/915009
You just have to find how to get output in rake directly